# Hivecontext.sql returns empty result spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am creating hive context and querying hive table like below,
The spark context is created using yarn-cluster

```
HiveContext hv = new HiveContext(sc)
hv.sql("use schema")
val df = hv.sql(query)
```

However it returns an empty dataframe.

However if I run the query directly in hive environment it returns valid values. What could be the issue

Comment: `val hv: HiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)`

Comment: @philantrovert: what difference does this make ??

Comment: `HiveContext hv` is syntactically wrong if you're using scala.

Comment: @philantrovert : But will this impact the issue ?

Comment: I'm not sure how are you even getting past the first line. Spark should throw an error right away. Which Spark ver?

Comment: @philantrovert : Spark does not throw error.Spark 2.10 version 1.6

Comment: My guess is that you have not setup hive correctly for Spark. More specifically `hive-site.xml,  core-site.xml hdfs-site.xml`must be present in your `conf`folder as described in in the apache [spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a dataframe in spark can be considered as a map to retrieve/compute data,it will not materialized until the data is needed.
In order to fetch the data, you can use df.collect()